# InvalidCastException in my C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, events, exception

I get an exception where i didn't get an exception before and i simply don't know why.
I have made a delete button that deletes data in a datagrid(WPF).

```
        private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            if (dataGrid.SelectedItem != null) {
                ((DataRowView)dataGrid.SelectedItem).Row.Delete();
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("Venligst valg et materiale som skal slettes");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            LogFile.ExceptionToLog(exception);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

It's on the fourth line of code where i get an exception that tells me i can't make this cast. I was wondering why, because like i said before, i have been able to do it before.

[image]

**Edit 1:** This is the datagrid

[image]

**Edit 2:**

```
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="424" Width="1037" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Testbinding}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=MaterialeBetegnelse}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Materialbetegnelse" Width="804"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Antal}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Antal" Width="75"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=akr}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="á kr" Width="75"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Ialt}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="I alt" Width="75"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Please post the full error trace as text.

Comment: Show the code, which populates `DataBindingGridOrderSheet`. Do you use `ItemsSource` binding?

Comment: @darophi Have you now binded SelectedItem like SelectedItem="{Binding SomeItem}" .

Comment: I have added a picture with the Datagrid

Comment: @darophi: could you post a *code* instead of cropped screenshots?

Comment: @darophi while in debug mode, place a breakpoint at opening brace of if statement and bring your mouse over SelectedItem in this line dataGrid.SelectedItem != null, placing mouse over SelectedItem will give the type of object contained in it. Then you can properly cast it.

Comment: Well, i know now that it is of type DataBindingGridOrderSheet, but that is not what i want it to be. I have not figured out data binding one hundred procent yet. But before i made the binding it was DataRowView, so i am confused as of why it is like this now. With the DataBindingGridOrderSheet i am not able to call .Row.Delete on the item.

Comment: Might sound dumb, but have you checked if you have a selectedRow at all? Split your call into a `var selIt = dataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView; if(selIt != null) { selIt.Row.Delete(); }` and check via the debugger if the selected item is filled and of which type it is.

Comment: It actually is null. But i don't get why. The datagrid.Selected is allright. After the cast it is null.

Comment: Been a while since I used a datagrid but why not use [datagridview.currentrow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: This is wpf. Pretty sure that datagridview is windows forms.

Comment: @darophi: It is. I forgot it was wpf when looking over the exception/code, sorry.

Comment: The exception is painfully clear: you have a `SelectedItem` value of `DataBindingGridOrderSheet`, but are trying to cast it to `DataRowView`. With a good [mcve] it would be trivial to understand where the problem lies, and likely would not be hard to propose a fix as well. Without a good code example, it's not possible to say much of anything useful about the code.